# Equivalent conditions on tensor product and product of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, etale-cohomology

( Background: These is one part of a critera for commutative rings $ f:A \rightarrow B$
 to be *etale*. )

---

It is claimed that the following two conditions **1   & 2 are equivalent.**

> 1. The multiplication map 
>      $$ p: B \otimes _A B \rightarrow B$$ 
>      is the projection on to a summand. There exists another commutative ring $q: B \otimes _A B \rightarrow R$ such that $p$ and $q$ induces isomorphism 
>      $$ B \otimes_A B \rightarrow B \times R $$

and

> 2. There exists an idempotent element $e \in B \otimes_A B$ such that $p$ induces an isomorphism $$(B \otimes_A B)[1/e] \simeq B$$
>      under localization at $e$.

I can prove 1=>2. But I can't prove 2=>1. Help would be appreciated : )

Comment: For any idempotent $e$ in any commutative ring $R$, the localization $R[1/e]$ is isomorphic to $(1-e)R$. Also, $R$ is isomorphic to $(1-e)R \times eR$. In particular, this applies for $R=B \otimes_{A} B$.

Comment: Yea. so what i'm struggling is to prove iso of $(1-e)R$ and $R[1/e]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring and $e$ an idempotent.

So $e^2=e$ or, perhaps written in a more suitable form for this question : $e(e-1) = 0$.

In particular if you invert $e$, then $e-1 = e^{-1} 0 = 0$ so $e=1$. *Inverting an idempotent turns it into $1$*.

In particular, you have a factorization of the canonical morphism as $R\to R/(e-1)\to R[1/e]$.

Conversely, if you kill $e-1$, you get $e=1$, so $e$ is invertible, so you also get a factorization of the canonical morphism as $R\to R[1/e]\to R/(e-1)$. It's then easy to check that these give you an isomorphism $R[1/e]\cong R/(e-1)$